# Is it possible to have a UEFI boot loader like GRUB2 load a legacy OS?

Tags: boot, bios, grub, uefi

I need to run legacy Sophos UTM (SuseLinux) baremetal on my mini PC but it is UEFI only. I cannot use a VM because the computer is not powerful enough. My only hope is the possibility of booting up in UEFI with GRUB2 or similar, and then loading the legacy OS.

Is this possible and how would I do it? Links would be appreciated. I don't see this anywhere but almost all computers can just enable legacy boot. This computer can't do that, even checked with the manufacturer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Booting a BIOS-mode OS on an EFI-based computer is possible *if and only if* the EFI includes a Compatibility Support Module (CSM). If this feature exists in the firmware, I know of three programs that can use it:

- **The firmware's built-in boot manager** -- If the firmware includes a CSM, then the built-in boot manager can boot BIOS-mode OSes. Typically, you'll see an option to boot from the hard disk (often specified by model name) in the built-in boot manager. How you access the built-in boot manager varies from one computer to another.
- **The rEFIt boot manager for Macs** -- For Macs *only,* the old [rEFIt boot manager](http://refit.sourceforge.net/) can boot BIOS-mode OSes. The process for doing so is fairly painless and automatic once rEFIt is installed; BIOS-mode OSes should show up in the boot menu. Note that, although rEFIt can work on EFI-based PCs, the ability to boot BIOS-mode OSes does not work on them; this is a Mac-only feature. Note also that rEFIt is no longer under active development.
- **My rEFInd boot manager for Macs or UEFI PCs** -- My [rEFInd boot manager,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) which is a fork of rEFIt, includes its ability to launch BIOS-mode OSes on Macs, and extends that ability to work on UEFI-based PCs. On PCs, though, this feature is inactive by default; you must edit the `refind.conf` configuration file, uncomment the `scanfor` line, and ensure that `hdbios` (or other options for external media) is included among the options.

In all three cases, it's usually necessary to ensure that the CSM is active in the firmware setup utility. Many computers ship with the CSM disabled, so you may need to track it down and enable this feature. Unfortunately, there's no standardization for how to do this, so you should check your computer's documentation, ask in a computer-specific forum, or just poke around to find it.

In theory, support for launching BIOS-mode OSes could be added to EFI-mode GRUB. In practice, I know of no plans to do so.

If your computer lacks a CSM, then I know of no way to launch a BIOS-mode OS; **however....**

You say that the OS you want to run is a SUSE variant. I'm not familiar with the specific OS you mention, but there's very little difference between BIOS-based and EFI-based Linux installations. The *only* critical difference, in fact, is in boot loaders. Thus, if you can get the target OS installed and then install an appropriate EFI-mode boot loader for Linux, it should work. You could install it by transferring an installation from another computer or by hacking the boot loader on the installation medium.

One possible caveat is that you mention this is for a "mini PC." Such systems often have 32-bit EFIs, but most Linux distributions give short shrift to 32-bit EFI-based systems. There are Web pages devoted to installing Linux on such systems, but I don't have any URLs handy at the moment. You can either install a 32-bit distribution or install a 64-bit distribution along with a 32-bit boot loader that can boot a 64-bit kernel. (GRUB 2 can do this.)